# Usign Mosek for CVXR

Tags: r, optimization, cvx, mosek, cvxr

I have already installed 3 times Mosek. It is working in python but CVXR (r package) function installed_solvers() is not able to find MOSEK. 
[image]

I'm working on a MACos Mojave. I installed Mosek via conda comand, got an academic license, create a folder in the home directory with the name mosek and put the license file in it. Then I tested in jupyter lab the following script https://docs.mosek.com/8.1/pythonapi/design.html#hello-world-in-mosek and getting the result
Solution x = 2.0 , so Mosek is working.
Then I installed reticulate, use the default directory, replace it by 
use_python("/Users/apple/anaconda3")
and 
use_python("/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6")
In any of them, the function installed_solvers() has found mosek. My session info is the following
[image]

The documentation in https://cvxr.rbind.io/cvxr_examples/cvxr_using-other-solvers/ doesn't really say how to solve the problem. Somebody has found the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to replicate, and errors are unfortunately very silent. But based on the source code, https://rdrr.io/cran/CVXR/src/R/mosek-solver.R, I tried all requirements

```
reticulate::py_module_available(module = "numpy")
reticulate::py_module_available(module = "scipy.sparse")
reticulate::py_module_available(module = "mosek")
```

to find that I was actually missing scipy in my Python environment. After installing that, it worked as documented..

If this doesn't help you, then try manually importing the solver:

```
msk = MOSEK()
import_solver(msk)
```

and see where that leads to.

Comment: Thanks for your help with your commands I found that `reticulate` was not finding `mosek` and I just updated my R and it work.